# How to populate data from Data Relationship in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created 2 DE(DE1 and DE2). DE1 is Sendable De and DE2 is not sendable.

In DE1 we have field Email(Primary Key), Fname, Lname, City
In DE2 we have field City(Primary Key), PIN

I have created Data relationship between DE1(Email field) and DE2(City field).

Now how to combined both DE by the Data Relationship?
I want to create another DE by Data Relationship which will combined both DE field in below sequence-
Email, Fname, Lname, City, Pin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the purpose of data relationships. You use data relationships to filter data in one data extension based on fields in the second data extension. So in your case you would be joining DE1 to DE2 using the City field as the joining field between both. Then if you knew you wanted all the people from DE1 where the PIN was 1234, you could do this filtering from DE1 using the data relationship.

To merge the data in two data extensions you would use a query in Automation Studio. Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT DE1.[Email], DE1.[Fname], DE1.[Lname], DE1.[City], DE2.[Pin]
FROM DE1 INNER JOIN DE2 ON DE1.[City] = DE2.[City]
```

Note you need to make the data extension that will hold this data manually before you run the query and use that data extension as the target of the query.

Comment: Thank you Jarrett for clarification. Yes, I usually do it by query activity in automation studio. However I was going through Data Relationship topic, so thought to try it.

Comment: @Alok: as Jarretts answer is the correct way to handle it please mark his answer as correct so that others can easily identify this as a resolved question when looking for a similar solution.